# Finding the Polynomial Convex Hull

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $‎‎X$ ‎be a‎ ‎compact set ‎in $‎‎‎C$. Then the polynomial convex hull of $‎‎‎X$ ‎is‎ $‎‎\hat{X}=\{z\in ‎‎\mathbb{C}: |p(z)‎‎‎|‎\leq \Vert‎ z\Vert‎_X \textrm{for all polynomials } p\}$‎.‎‎‎‎‎ Now I need to prove this: the polynomially convex hull of ‎‎$‎X$ ‎is ‎union ‎of ‎$‎‎‎X$‎ ‎‎‎and the bounded components of ‎$‎‎C−X$‎. Thanks

Comment: This is Proposition VII.5.3 in Conway's Functional Analysis.

Answer (score 2):

If $z \in X$, it's obvious by definition that $z \in \hat{X}$.

If $z$ is in an unbounded component of $\mathbb C \backslash X$, Runge's theorem can be used to get a polynomial $p$ such that, say, $|p(z)-1|<1/2$ while $|p(w)|<1/2$ for $w \in X$.

Finally, if $z$ is in a bounded component $V$ of $\mathbb C \backslash X$, the closure $\overline{V}$ of $V$ is compact and the maximum modulus principle says the maximum absolute value of a polynomial $p$ on $\overline{V}$ is attained on the boundary of $\overline{V}$, which is contained in $X$.

Comment: I really appreciate your help

Comment: Apologies for the late comment, but do you mind explaining how to obtain such $p$? I see that Runge gives a polynomial such that $\vert p(w)\vert <1/2$ for $w\in X$, but I'm not sure how to achieve the condition $\vert p(z)-1\vert<1/2$.

Comment: Let $K$ be the union of $X$, the bounded components of $\mathbb C \backslash X$, and $\{z\}$.  Take a holomorphic function $f$ on a neighbourhood of $K$ such that $f(z) = 1$ and $f = 0$ on the rest of $K$.  Approximate it by a polynomial...

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of including $\{z\}$ to the compact set for Runge. Thank you!