# Is polynomially convex strictly weaker than convex?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Define the *polynomially convex hull* of a compact set $K$ to be the set

$K\hat{} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |p(z)| \le \max_{x \in K} |p(x)| \text{ for every polynomial } p \}$

If $K\hat{} = K$ then $K$ is *polynomially convex*.

I'm wondering to what extent does this agree with the "normal" sense of convexity in the Complex plane, that is containing all its line segments.

I believe that for example the polynomially convex hull of two points is *not* the line segment between them, since a polynomial could obtain a max on the midpoint between them, thus be less than the maximum of the two points.

Given that, is it correct to say we can recover the "normal" definition by considering only *linear* functions, which would make this a generalization and weakening of the concept (since it'd be harder to find points where this was true, thus the hull is smaller)?

Comment: You probably mean $\max_{x \in K} |p(x)|$ right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The polynomially convex hull of $K$ is the union of $K$ with all bounded components of $\Bbb C \setminus K$, see for example [Finding the Polynomial Convex Hull](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056003/finding-the-polynomial-convex-hull).

If $K$ is compact and convex then $\Bbb C \setminus K$ is connected and has no bounded component. Therefore every compact convex set is also polynomially convex.

The above characterization makes it also easy to construct examples that a polynomially convex set need not be convex: We only have to find a non-convex set $K$ such that $\Bbb C \setminus K$ is connected. A simple example would be the upper half of the unit circle:
$$
 K = \{ z \in \Bbb C : |z| = 1, \operatorname{Im}(z) \ge 0 \} \, .
$$